# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /home/customer/www/abc.com/public_html/wp-includes/cl

Tags: wordpress, memory, size

I am getting this error and tries to change memory limit in php.ini file but not able to find this file so created new php.ini file and changed memory limit over there still not resolved

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes) in /home/customer/www/abc.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-dependencies.php on line 260

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: The specific location may vary. You have two ways: ask to your provider, or do a search from CLI. Is that Linux? If so, try `/etc/php`